# Defining a series of functions in DigitalMicrograph scripting

Tags: dm-script

I have a set of functions inside a class that I need to define. Each passes a different value into another function:

```
void function00(object self, taggroup tg) self.otherfunction(tg,0,0)
void function01(object self, taggroup tg) self.otherfunction(tg,0,1)
void function02(object self, taggroup tg) self.otherfunction(tg,0,2)
void function03(object self, taggroup tg) self.otherfunction(tg,0,3)
void function04(object self, taggroup tg) self.otherfunction(tg,0,4)
```

I have 100 of these functions and I'd prefer not to define each one separately. Considering the above example I'd like to do something like:

```
for(number i=0; i<5; i++){
    void function0+i(object self, taggroup tg) self.otherfunction(tg,0,i)
}
```

which doesn't work on it's own. Any suggestions?

For some more context I create a series of check boxes inside 2 for loops with the following:

```
BOXinsides.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateCheckBox(label,0,"function"+i+j).DLGIdentifier("#function"+i+j))
```

and I need to define all the functions in some sensible way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DigitalMicrograph scripting does not allow this type of template code. However, you can solve your problem by linking all checkbox items to the same action-method. The signature of the action method passed in the TagGroup which is the checkbox item itself. You can use this to derive information from it, for example by looking at a checkbox property such as its title:

```
class myUI : UIframe
{
  void generalFunction( object self , tagGroup checkTg )
  {
    // checkTg is the taggroup of the checkbox which fired the method.
    // Use its Title to get back the running value!

    string label = checkTg.DLGGetTitle()                
    Result( "\n label of checkbox:" + label )
    number i = val( right( label, len( label ) - 1 ) )   
    Result( "\n running index:" + i )
  }

  TagGroup CreateCheckboxes( object self )
  {
    TagGroup checkboxGroup = DLGCreateGroup()
    for ( number i = 0 ; I < 5 ; i++ )
    {
     checkboxGroup.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateCheckBox( "C" + I , 0 , "generalFunction" ) )
    }
    return checkboxGroup 
  }

  TagGroup CreateDLGTags( object self )
  {
    TagGroup dlg, dlgitems
    dlg = DLGCreateDialog( "Test" , dlgitems )
    dlgitems.DLGAddElement( self.CreateCheckboxes() )
    return dlg
  }

  object Init( object self )
  {
    return self.super.init( self.CreateDLGTags() )
  }
 }

// MAIN SCRIPT calling the dialog
{
  Object dlg = Alloc(myUI).Init()
  dlg.pose()
}
```

You can also 'attach' information directly to the checkbox. Checkboxes are - as all dialog items - really just specific TagGroup objects to which you can add whatever you like. In the example below, I'm adding an additional tag with a random number:

```
class myUI : UIframe
{
  void generalFunction( object self , tagGroup checkTg )
  {
    // checkTg is the taggroup of the checkbox which fired the method.
    // Use its Title to get back the running value!

    string label = checkTg.DLGGetTitle()                
    Result( "\n label of checkbox:" + label )
    number rnd
    if ( checkTG.TagGroupGetTagAsNumber( "Random NR", rnd ) )
    {
      Result( "\n Random number:" + rnd )
    }
  }

  TagGroup CreateCheckboxes( object self )
  {
    TagGroup checkboxGroup = DLGCreateGroup()
    for ( number i = 0; I < 5 ; i++ )
    {
     TagGroup checkbox = DLGCreateCheckBox( "C" + I , 0 , "generalFunction" )
     checkbox.TagGroupSetTagAsNumber( "Random NR", Random() )
     checkboxGroup.DLGAddElement( checkbox )
    }
    return checkboxGroup 
  }

  TagGroup CreateDLGTags( object self )
  {
    TagGroup dlg, dlgitems
    dlg = DLGCreateDialog( "Test" , dlgitems )
    dlgitems.DLGAddElement( self.CreateCheckboxes() )
    return dlg
  }

  object Init( object self )
  {
    return self.super.init( self.CreateDLGTags() )
  }
 }

// MAIN SCRIPT calling the dialog
{
  Object dlg=Alloc(myUI).Init()
  dlg.pose()
}
```

[image]